# What is the real world difference between 2020 8th generation iPad and 5th generation iPad mini?

Tags: ipad

According to Apple website, the iPad mini has the following differences (these are some of them):

- Wide colour capture for photos and Live Photos
- Fully laminated display
- Anti-reflective coating
- Wide colour display (P3)
- True Tone display

In real world usage, how would those differ, especially screen features. Are those worth spending the extra money on the mini or should I stick with an 8th generation iPad?

(Also about the resolution, iPad mini has less resolution but more ppi, so what is the difference here?)

Comment: This might be better to ask how one feature works. Someone that knows True Tone might have no clue how to answer lamination. In the end - what’s the problem to be solved? If this is a buying question - let’s be clear what the options are and goals...

Comment: Yes i want to buy one for reading and watching as nowadays and especially with online learning, my eyesight is getting worse with viewing things in a small screen. Also i wanted a portable tablet so that is why i considered the iPad mini to begin with. But idk if i should stick to the 8th generation iPad or go to the iPad mini. 
Also sorry for late reply, i thought you only edited my post and I just realised you added a comment too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not something is "worth it" is highly subjective - noone can really answer that but yourself.

If you compare the displays side by side, you'll see the difference clearly. Are you going to be doing that on a daily basis? - Probably not.

However I would say that the fully laminated display especially makes a big difference in how you perceive the display. This is one of those "I didn't need it until I saw it, and then I really needed it" things.

The resolution versus PPI is simply because the physical size of the iPad Mini's display is smaller. Even though the resolution is smaller, the physical size is so small, that the number of pixels per inch is actually higher.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, how is the laminated display different, what does it add to the display? 
Especially because i will primarily use it for reading and watching lectures as my eye sight is getting weaker and weaker with reading stuff on a phone screen, so i am interested in having a better display but in the same time don't know weather i should pay 80 dollars more on a smaller screen. Also i was considering the iPad mini because i want it to be mobile and carry it anywhere easily, so that is the second reason why I considered it

Comment: It doesn't "add" something as such - it is more like it subtracts something. If you look at a non-laminated touch display, it is evident that the display consists of multiple layers. If you look at a laminated display, it looks like the text is just written on the glass. It's one of thse "you'll know it when you see it" things - hard to explain. In your case, go to a store and see both iPads in real life and make a decision. If you have bad eye sight, I would have thought that you wanted the bigger display - better color accuracy, etc. is really of less importance then.

Comment: Hopefully will do this once i save enough money to buy it (hopefully someday in this month too) thank you for the help, also i know what you mean by you'll know it when you see it as hardware changes are harder to describe unless you actually experience them.